# Detect and remove comments from beginning of a file

Tags: regex, git, automation, comments

[Discount](https://github.com/Orc/discount)'s `configure.sh` script generates some dynamic comments at the start of the `config.h` file:

```
/*
 * configuration for markdown, generated Fri 28 Jan 2011 16:13:46 EST
 * by tim@Orion.local
 */
#ifndef __AC_MARKDOWN_D
#define __AC_MARKDOWN_D 1

[...]
```

Which makes for some useless patches when embedding discount inside a git project, so I remove them before committing. I want to automate the output from `configure.sh` so I can upgrade discount inside the project quicker, but I'm not that well versed with awk/sed. I've got this line in my script:

```
tail -n +5 config.h > ../discount-config/config.h
```

But I'd like to replace this with something more future-proof, so it won't mangle the file if later versions of discount have more/less than 4 lines of comments.

Comment: can't you just modify `configure.sh` to not write that comment?

Comment: Why do you want to store a generated file inside the repository? It's usually better to store the script which you can run to generate the file after checking out your project.

Comment: @SilentGhost `configure.sh` is part of discount's git repository, I don't want to modify that

Comment: @ssmir The upstream repository originally had it stored in the repository, so I'd rather not change it. Also, this way it builds straight from the clone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)?

For example, if you can assume that the top comment will always start at the first line of the file:

```
$ cat test.h
/*
 * configuration for markdown, generated Fri 28 Jan 2011 16:13:46 EST
 * by tim@Orion.local
 */
#ifndef __AC_MARKDOWN_D
#define __AC_MARKDOWN_D 1

/*
 * Test
 */

int x;
$ sed '1,/^ *\*\/ *$/ { d; }' test.h
#ifndef __AC_MARKDOWN_D
#define __AC_MARKDOWN_D 1

/*
 * Test
 */

int x;
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought there would be an elegant solution like that, but I didn't know enough about sed to write one.